# How to merge a lot of smaller tables with single-column differences into a one bigger table?

Tags: database, database-design

I have a multiple same tables (14 for now), with a only `foreignKey` column difference. Some of them are:

```
   DatasetGraphTable
+-------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
|       datasetID         | parameterID          | value              |
+-------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
|       988               |   12                 | "value one"        |
|       988               |   13                 | "value two"        |
|       989               |   12                 | "value three"      |
+-------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+

   AgentGraphTable
+-------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
|       agentID           | parameterID          | value              |
+-------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
|       200               |   12                 | "value agent one"  |
|       201               |   13                 | "value agent two"  |
|       220               |   12                 | "value agent three"|
+-------------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
```

`datasetID` is foreign key to table `Dataset`, `agentID` is a foreign key to table `Agent`, etc. `parameterID` is a foreign key to the table `Parameters`, which is a codebook of all parameters, and every table use it. So, as you can see, All tables are the same, except first column, which is a foreign key to different tables. Is there a way to merge all these `GraphTables` into a single `GraphTable`? If not, how can I improve this database design?

Comment: Welcome to Software Engineer Stack Exchange. If you somehow make those 14 tables into a single one, you'll end up with a table with 14 diffferent FK, many of them with null values. You should ask yourself this question: do these 14 tables represent the same conceptual entity? Physical implementation similarity is not enough a reason to consider them to be the same.

Comment: From just looking at the two tables you gave as an example I would not dare to make any prediction whether it makes sense to merge the 14 tables into one, or not. One needs to see more examples, and know the use cases and queries where these tables are involved. Voting to close as "opinionated", there is barely enough information in this question to give you a useful answer, and the accepted one might be right or wrong, I could only flip a coin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a foreign key difference, is actually a very good reason here for having a separate table, with a distinct column name for the foreign key, in all 14 cases.

The repetitive similarities in table structure should not blind you to the fundamental differences in the table relationships, which would be muddied together if the 14 tables were collapsed into 1.

Taken to the extreme, trying to make all database structure and naming generic leaves you with an "EAV" schema, which is minimal in structure and highly flexible, but also highly inefficient (perhaps ruinously so), devoid of useful naming, and the real structural design and constraints become implicit (and thus difficult to discern or enforce).